# Have multiple components build one HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently my app has a data service that makes a http request to the server for data. Each component makes an individual call to this service to get the data that it needs.

```
public getHospitals() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/hospitals/")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Hospital, json));
}

public getClinics() {
    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl + "/clinics/")
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Clinic, json));
}
```

When I load my example page, I have a Hospital component and a Clinic component. These two components call the respective method in the data service.

I have recently extended the server to allow a single request which specifies what data it needs. An example of how this is called can be seen below.

```
public getLocalData(body) {
    const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
    return this._http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(body), options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}

public getHospitals() {
    return this.getLocalData(["Hospitals"])
        .map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Hospital, json.Hospitals));
}

public getClinics() {
    return this.getLocalData(["Clinics"])
        .map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Clinic, json.Clinics));
}
```

This could instead be called like this, which would return back all of the data: `const localData = this.getLocalData(["Hospitals", "Clinics"]);`

My questions is, how do I modify these two components to build the body parameter for the `getLocalData` method and make only one http request?

EDIT: I am also looking to scale this so that eventually I can have say 10+ components that each have their own set of local data to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your service is called to get data you could wait until all of the `ngZone` microtasks have finished (which includes any other requests that might be made to the service) and then fire off a single `http` request. You would need to modify the `getLocalData` method to return an `rxjs` `Subject` and once the data comes back from the server you can emit data on the subjects so they can be passed back to the appropriate callers.

***Disclaimer*** I am not entirely sure if this is the best way to approach this problem but the above should work.

Here is the modified service and `getLocalData` method.

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/first";
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

// ...

public getHospitals() {
    return this.getLocalData("Hospitals")
        .map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Hospital, json.Hospitals));
}

public getClinics() {
    return this.getLocalData("Clinics")
        .map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Clinic, json.Clinics));
}

private requests = {};
private isAggregating = false;
private getLocalData(dataKey): Subject {
    this.requests[dataKey] = this.requests[dataKey] || new Subject();

    if(!this.isAggregating){
        this.isAggregating = true;
        this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first().subscribe(() => {
            var requests = this.requests;
            this.requests = {};
            this.isAggregating = false;

            const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });

            this._http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(Object.keys(requests)), options)
                .map(res => {
                    return res.json();
                }).subscribe((data) => {
                    Object.keys(data)
                        .filter((key) => requests[key])
                        .forEach((key)=>{
                            requests[key].next(data[key]);
                            requests[key].complete();
                        });
                });
       });
   }

   return this.requests[dataKey];
```

}

I am not sure how to rewrite it so that the individual service methods can request multiple sets of data as is indicated in your question but I am sure there is a way to get create with the `requests` map to enable requesting multiple sets instead of a single set.

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/acrzvHN7IxDjdT5qcndC)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to implement something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalDataService {
    private getLocalData(body) {
        const headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
        return this._http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(body), options)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

    public getHospitals() {
        if (!this.pendingRequest) {
            this.pendingRequest = this.getLocalData(["Hospitals", "Clinics"]);
            this.cleanUpSubscription = this.pendingRequest.subscribe(() => this.cleanUp(), () => this.cleanUp());
        }

        return this.pendingRequest.map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Hospital, json.Hospitals));
    }

    public getClinics() {
        if (!this.pendingRequest) {
            this.pendingRequest = this.getLocalData(["Hospitals", "Clinics"]);
            this.cleanUpSubscription = this.pendingRequest.subscribe(() => this.cleanUp(), () => this.cleanUp());
        }

        return this.pendingRequest.map(json => automapper.map(typeof (JSON), Clinic, json.Clinics));
    }

    private cleanUp() {
        if (this.cleanUpSubscription) {
            this.cleanUpSubscription.unsubscribe();
            this.cleanUpSubscription = null;
        }

        this.pendingRequest = null;
    }

    private pendingRequest: Observable<Response> = null;
    private cleanUpSubscription: Subscription = null;
}
```

I've cached observable in order to return if for subsequent request. So if we have one request in progress (let's say Hospitals), and ask API for Clinics until Hospitals are not returned yet we won't make additional request. Existing observable will be returned and both components (Hospitals and Clinics) and can handle response separately.

Also I've added some cleanUp code in order to remove cached Observable after request is completed. Subsequent request will hit API once again.

Note: I haven't tested this code, so some additional changes can be required.

Comment: How is this going to scale and be extendable? What would I do once I get up to 20 different types of data calls? Not all of those calls would need to be made for each page so I wouldn't want to request all of them.

Comment: There is nothing said that you have more than two components in your question. So update your question with your actual requirements. If you want to make one request for several independent components I think you should have one parent component which is aware about its children components (Clinics, Hospitals, etc). And when all child components are loaded (ngAfterViewInit) parent component can perform network request and pass Observable into child components through Input parameter.